# What happens to currencies in mist if computer goes offlinei

Tags: mist

I downloaded Mist as my desktop storage, my question is what would happen if my computer goes offline or say we go move and my computer would stay offline for a long period of time. I am new to the cryptocurrency and blockchain world, thank you for any input

Answer (score 0):

When you come back online, it'll take your node a while to sync up.  An alternative to Mist would be something like Metamask, where you wouldn't have to sync a local Ethereum node.

Answer (score 0):

Mist allows you to see how many ether and tokens you (and everyone else) have according to network consensus. If you exit Mist, the information will be out of date; you'll need to sync up to see everything.

Mist also allows you, using your private key, to authorize transactions involving your accounts. If the only machine using your accounts is your desktop then as soon as you turn on your mist, you can transact on the blockchain (otherwise, you may need to sync up to avoid reusing a nonce).

Your accounts continue to exist when your computer is off -- it's just that no one can authorize transactions to send ether from the accounts on your computer or call contracts using those account. In fact, you can still receive tokens/ether while your computer is off-line; this is essentially what "cold-storage" of a wallet is.

Comment: Thank you! It is actually taking a while to sync up right now

Answer (score 0):

That's the first question I answer in this article!
The account info is stored on nodes across the network. Your balance will continue to exist even if you never bring your computer online. What you need to do is export the private keys:

https://iwebconsultation.com/getting-started-with-ethereum-and-bitcoin-complete-beginners-guide-to-mining-and-buying-cryptocurrency/